# Ipa creation using any script(ipa creation from other ipa )

Tags: ios, macos, ipa

basically my project based on books(combination of pdf's and xml's). Due to some reasons we are maintaining more than ten provisioning profiles.when ever new device udid comes up we need to create another provisioning profile(as per the requirement). For each time building i need to put some provisioning and replacing books in my xcode, this is causing more time consuming. I seen many scripts but all those not full filling the scenario.

**Questions:**

1.Is it possible to develop another application (mac osx) to make ipa which is taking an input of provisioning file, my code(ios) and books then compile finally giving output as .ipa file for giving code?

2.is any other way to reduce time consuming for the ipa creation?

If any possible  please give me some  idea to make it true , your suggestions is also more important on this.Thanks in advance to every one.

**new  question for generating Ipa from other ipa file**

I followed your approach,But can any one please let me know ,i created a ipa file and now i want to modify the content of ipa and also provisioning profile will it possible?

Comment: Consider using Jenkins (formerly known as Hudson).

Comment: Agreed with Till, use Testflight or Hockeyapp http://www.hockeyapp.net/ you can also get live crash reports.

Answer (score 2):

If you have an ipa created using older provisioning profile and the code hasn't changed between getting next provisioning profile then there is a way to do it.

```
You can write a script from following steps:

1) Change the .ipa that you already have to .zip and extract zip contents. This would reveal Payload folder that has YourApp.app folder
2) Right click on YourApp.app folder and show package contents
3) find embedded.mobileprovision and delete it. Drag your new .mobileprovision file into this location and rename it to say embedded.mobileprovision.
4) Find and delete any _CodeSignature or CodeResources files/folders
5) From terminal delete .DS_Store files in Payload and YourApp.app folder
6) Use Codesign utility in /usr/bin/codesign to codesign your .app. Here is command for it:

codesign -f -s "iPhone Distribution: Your company Name" PathToYourApp

In your keychain utility find the certificate name that is used to create the distribution profile and match it to first argument in codesign -f -s
7) finally zip the payload to form an ipa

zip -r YourApp.ipa Payload
```

Comment: You actually do not resign the app if all you did is adding a device to your AdHoc provisioning profile. The App itself does not maintain the list of allowed devices. All you need to do is install the new version of the profile on the "new" device, then install the App itself.

Comment: I thought the provisioning profile inside the app maintains that list of devices it can install on. When the list gets updated new provisioning profile replaces old one so app needs to be code signed again is what I thought. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Thanks for your fast response I try to implement as per @0x8badf00d.will this process work even for the different profiles also.

Comment: i tried it out and could prepare a ipa with the edited profile,thanks for that.My requirement is that i should be able to change the contents of the books folder that is presented at absolute path.and i tried to edit the folder and created a ipa but my ipa was not getting installed and given a error that the resource folder is modified..plz help if u have any further idea

Comment: @efrank Looks like you have modified contents of the app and didn't codesign it after modifications. Codesign is like seal to App contents. To modify contents of app you need to break the seal, and application with broken seal wouldn't install on device with given certificate. So codesign the app after modifying contents of the app.

Comment: i also code signed it after breaking and modifying the contents,but still gave the same error.If u don't mind i would like to know if you are ever tried to change the content.If not can u plz try once so that u could understand the error better than me and i can be helped.

Comment: @efrank I modified plist files, and it worked fine. Are you sure you removed any .DS_Store files and _CodeSignatures, CodeResources files/folders using terminal not Finder. Because Finder leaves .DS_Store files in folders.

Comment: i removed DS_Store files and _CodeSignatures, CodeResources files/folders using terminal,but didn't modify the info.plist file.Can u plz guide me how to modify it.and while using codesign -f -s "*****"...,i have given a alphanumeric string by seeing it in keychain access and it is common for any profile ,am i doing correct.

Comment: @0x8badf00d: plz help me i am in great need,sorry for bothering u.

Comment: @efrank send me an email testusermac123@gmail.com with your Skype id or any other screensharing software I can take a look at it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5663/discussion-between-efrank-and-0x8badf00d)

Comment: +1 @ 0x8badf00d  for your great support I too followed your steps and struck same like eFrank can you please give some more information for my updated question.once again thanks.

Comment: @ajay, I don't know think code signing would work as expected if you add or delete files from the app bundle. Its app executable or ResourceRules.plist that might keep track of number of files in the application bundle and size. Also the app executable knows about all resources and have track of these files. I might be wrong. I don't know how to add delete files in the app bundle and just codesign it. Ask it as separate question.

Comment: but i am trying to modify only which i placed resources which is i placed in absolute path.there is no dependency with those content.I dont know abt i am doing right or wrong but i need it.

Comment: @ajay, when you codesign it using codesign -f -s can you use -vvvv to check what failed